# Does leaving empty PCB holes filled with solder matter?

Tags: pcb, soldering

If I was soldering and I accidentally filled an unnecessary hole on my PCB with solder, is that a problem or can I just leave it filled?

Thank you for answering this ! All help is appreciated!

(And yes, I do know this is a beginner question. That's because I'm a beginner.)

Comment: Care to explain what kind of problem you expect it to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not an issue.

In a (huge) quantity production setting you might think about the wasted material (and there's that rumor about the mass fraction of the Saturn V) but for an ordinary prototype it should make no difference.

Should you later decide you wish to put a component lead or wire there, you may need to clean out the hole with flux and desolder braid, or some other method of your choice.

Comment: Can you point a reference about this Saturn V rumor? Tried Google it but no luck there.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you will later want to put a component lead or other wire through that hole, you can leave it filled.